# Show model output images in leaflet map by TimeSlider

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet

I am new to Leaflet basically. I want to display my model output images in leaflet by a time slider which will show every 1 hour images.

I am able to display an image in leaflet by using ImageOverlay. Below is the code to display an image.

```
var imageUrl = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/stylesheet/images/flash_count_1.png",
        imageBounds = [[-51, 0], [51,180]];

    L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).setOpacity(0.5).addTo(Lmap);

    Lmap.setMaxBounds(imageBounds);
```

I am also able to show the timeslider to the map by using it's timeslider plugin.

```
var endDate = new Date();
    endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 10);
    endDate.setUTCMinutes(0, 0, 0);
    var map = L.map('map_draw_area', {
        zoom: 5,
        fullscreenControl: true,
        timeDimension: true,
        timeDimensionControl: true,
        timeDimensionOptions:{
            timeInterval: "P10D/" + endDate.toISOString(),
            period: "PT1H",
            currentTime: endDate
        },    

        timeDimensionControlOptions: {
            autoPlay: false,
            playerOptions: {
                buffer: 10,
                transitionTime: 250,
                loop: true,
            }
        },
        center: [20.9517, 85.0985],
    });
```

Now what I want is to interact those images with the time slider.  So If the time slider have 2019-06-25T16:00:00.000Z (4PM [IST]), so I will show my 4pm image. if the time is 2019-06-25T17:00:00.000Z (5PM [IST]), then I want to show 5pm image and so on. I want to do it for 10 days.

I have attached 3 images of my model output and the time slider which I am using enter image description herejust for reference.

2019_06_21_05_00_00
[image: 2019_06_21_05_00_00]
2019_06_21_04_00_00
[image: 2019_06_21_05_00_00]
2019_06_21_06_00_00
[image]

here is the link of time slider that I used [Time slider example 14](http://apps.socib.es/Leaflet.TimeDimension/examples/example14.html)

Comment: What is your problem ??

Comment: @nAviD I want to show the images according to the time slider. Ex : if i have a,b and c Images for 1 AM, 2 AM and 3 AM then when the time slider comes to 1 AM show a Image, when it comes to 2 AM then show b image and so On

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution?

Comment: @LeoPessanha Yes I found it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to save the imageOverlay in a variable so you can remove it later and add another one, here is a simple code to do the job :

```
var imgOvr=null; //global variable
```

then :

```
...
imgOvr = L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).setOpacity(0.5).addTo(Lmap);
...
```

and to delete

```
if (map.hasLayer(imgOvr)) {
    map.removLayer(imgOvr);
// replace with new image :
// imgOvr = L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).setOpacity(0.5).addTo(Lmap);
```

Comment: I understand this, but how can I integrate both of these according to the time slider